# How to set and use session variables in shopify liquid file?

Tags: cookies, session-variables, shopify, liquid

I need to **set session variable in shopify** but did not find any documentation for this.

When user login to the shopify app, then it creates the session (or cookie), then how this can be done manually.
My requirements is to use some input data on particular page to another page that can be achieved by session variables.

Please reply if it is possible or not in Shopify. If possible, then please try to paste some code. If not, then how can I do this in Shopify.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot access session in shopify. You'll have to use a javascript solution of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever figured it out, but here's how I tracked a referral landing page using javascript:

I added a landing page with the code (https://www.myshopifysite.com/pages/StoreRef?ref=somerefferer) that redirects to the main shop page after storing the cookie.

```html
<script>
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
setCookie('referral',getParameterByName('ref', null,1));
window.location = 'http://www.myshopifysite.com';
</script>
```

Then, on some later page -- I added a page to check the cookie -- (https://www.myshopifysite.com/pages/CheckRef)

```html
<script>
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

//alert('cookie val:' + getCookie('referral'));
</script>
```

NOTES: 
This relies on the client having cookies turned 'on' on their browser, though I suspect most folks these days do.

Be careful with your domain names ("http://www.example.com" vs "http://example.com" can cause issues with the cookie -- among other things on Shopify, I've found.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script>
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
setCookie('referral',getParameterByName('ref', null,1));
window.location = 'http://www.myshopifysite.com';
</script>
```